# Add some text rows above columns header pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns in which one column header is "5" (5 is the number of time-series rows), the other is the "Value" column like this:

```
5   Value

2014-01-01 00:00:00 2.80

2014-01-01 00:15:00 2.97

2014-01-01 00:30:00 2.74

2014-01-01 00:45:00 2.54

2014-01-01 01:00:00 2.28
```

I would like to add some text rows above the two columns header when saving the data frame to *.dat (or *CSV) file format like this:

```
$Column1=Time (days)

$Column2=Temperature (°C)

5   Value

2014-01-01 00:00:00 2.80

2014-01-01 00:15:00 2.97

2014-01-01 00:30:00 2.74

2014-01-01 00:45:00 2.54

2014-01-01 01:00:00 2.28
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your csv with `to_csv` and reload your data with `read_csv` like this:

```
metadata = """\
$Column1=Time (days)
$Column2=Temperature (°C)
"""

# Write csv
with open('data.csv', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(metadata)
    df.to_csv(fp, sep='\t', index=False)

# Read csv
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', comment='$', sep='\t', parse_dates=[0])
```

```
>>> %cat 'data.csv'
$Column1=Time (days)
$Column2=Temperature (°C)
5   Value
2014-01-01 00:00:00 2.8
2014-01-01 00:15:00 2.97
2014-01-01 00:30:00 2.74
2014-01-01 00:45:00 2.54
2014-01-01 01:00:00 2.28


>>> df1
                    5  Value
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00   2.80
1 2014-01-01 00:15:00   2.97
2 2014-01-01 00:30:00   2.74
3 2014-01-01 00:45:00   2.54
4 2014-01-01 01:00:00   2.28
```